How to make OCR function work with Naps2 sdk and C#
I'm trying to write a simple application in C# that uses Naps2.sdk to scan text documents and save a searchable PDF using the OCR feature. However, the output is a PDF with non-selectable text. I'm using Ubuntu Linux and VSCode, and I have installed Naps2. The following NuGet packages are installed:
<PackageReference Include="NAPS2.Images" Version="1.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="NAPS2.Images.Gtk" Version="1.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="NAPS2.Sdk" Version="1.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="NAPS2.Tesseract.Binaries" Version="1.2.0"/>

The code is as follows:
using var scanningContext = new ScanningContext(new GtkImageContext());
var controller = new ScanController(scanningContext);

ScanDevice device = (await controller.GetDeviceList()).First();

var options = new ScanOptions
{
    Device = device,
    PaperSource = PaperSource.Feeder,
    PageSize = PageSize.A4,
    Dpi = 300
};

var images = new List<NAPS2.Images.ProcessedImage>();

int i = 1;
await foreach (var image in controller.Scan(options))
{
    image.Save($"page{i++}.jpg");
    images.Add(image);
    Console.WriteLine("Scanned a page!");
}

// scanningContext.OcrEngine = TesseractOcrEngine.Custom(@"/usr/lib/naps2/_linux/tesseract");

var pdfExporter = new PdfExporter(scanningContext);
await pdfExporter.Export("doc.pdf", images, ocrParams: new OcrParams("eng"));

I also tried setting scanningContext.OcrEngine using the commented line or with:
scanningContext.OcrEngine = TesseractOcrEngine.Bundled(@"/usr/lib/naps2/_linux/");

where I put the eng.traineddata file.
However, the result is the same. The application runs without any apparent errors, but the PDF does not contain selectable text.
Any ideas on this issue?
Thanks.
